# Screenshot image appears much bigger in size when pasted

Tags: screen-capture, copy-paste, image-capture

MacOS, Sonoma and even earlier versions, screenshot's image appears to be much bigger in size when pasted:

[image]

How can I get the same size when doing copy and paste please?

I really don't want to drag and resize every pasted image.

Comment: Where do you paste the pictures into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent macOS makes screenshots at 144 dpi on Retina displays, rather than the old standard of 72 dpi.
This should theoretically make no difference, because when pasted, an app ought to recognise the dpi setting & respect it. The image should be twice the resolution but displayed at the same size.

In practise, this often doesn't happen.
The only thing you can really do to deal with this is to resize the image.

You can do this in Automator & set it as a Service [Quick Action].
Launch Automator, open a new Quick Action; set Workflow recieves image files in Finder
Search Scale on the left & drag Scale Image into the workflow. It will ask you if you want to add a Copy action. Say Don't Add [we don't need a copy of the original for this, just a resized image]
Save. Give it a memorable name, in this case Resize Image 50%.

[image: Quick Action]

Then go to System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services
Find your new Action & give it a key command - something that won't conflict, like  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>

[image]
<sup>Pictures from Mojave, instructions are same up to Ventura [Sonoma untested].</sup>

Then, to resize, all you need is to select your image & hit the key command.
Done.

Answer (score 0):

**FOLLOW-UP:**

I tried to follow the accepted answer to resize the image to its 50%, however, the *resized image will look only half the size in preview*.

This creates a dilemma that ***it either looks too big on the web, or too small locally***. So now the question becomes,

Is there any tool that gives the consistent result, ***showing the same size both on the web and locally***?

I was planning to ask a *new* question, but I found the answer myself, thus putting here as a note for myself. The answer is,

*Use the browser* to view the local picture files that will be posted to the web. It will give consistent results.

Comment: This should be added to your original question and then this "answer" deleted.